# Skip iteration if response is null in async.jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, async.js, google-visualization

I'm using `asyncjs` to load the Google charts, it works fine but sometimes api from which I am getting figures for chart returns null values and it stops loading further charts.

here is my code

```
async.eachSeries($('.WeeklyGraph'), function(e, cb){
var ticker = $(e).data('coin');
// console.log(ticker);
$('#'+ticker+'loader').removeClass("hide-sideLoader");
$.getJSON('https://coincap.io/history/7day/'+ticker, function(data){
    // console.log(data);
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "Jan";
month[1] = "Feb";
month[2] = "Mar";
month[3] = "Apr";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "Jun";
month[6] = "Jul";
month[7] = "Aug";
month[8] = "Sep";
month[9] = "Oct";
month[10] = "Nov";
month[11] = "Dec";
    var CoinPrices = data['price'];
        $.each(CoinPrices, function(index, CoinObject){
            var date = new Date(CoinObject[0]);
            var day = date.getDate();
            var Month = date.getMonth();
            var hours = date.getHours()+ ":" + date.getMinutes();
            CoinObject[0] = day+" "+month[Month]+" "+hours;
        });  
        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', '');
        data.addColumn('number', '');
        data.addRows(CoinPrices);
        var options = {
            enableInteractivity: false,
           legend: {position: 'none'},
            hAxis: {
            title: '',
            baselineColor: 'none',
            ticks: [],
            gridlines: {color: 'none'}
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: '',
            baselineColor: 'none',
            ticks: [],
            gridlines: {color: 'none'}
        },
            colors: ['#74b42a', '#74b42a']
        };
        var chartID = ticker+'chart_div';
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(chartID));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        $('#'+ticker+'loader').addClass("hide-sideLoader");
        // $("#chartContent"+coinID).removeClass("hide-chart");
        });

    cb();
});

});
```

now the `data` variable where I am getting response, sometimes it returns null and further iterations are stop.

I have tried to set that

```
 if (data == null)
     return;
```

or

```
   if (data == null)
     return true;
```

but it stops all further iterations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `callback` function, to goto next iteration. i.e.

```
if(data == null){
     cb(); //in your case, cb is your callback function
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you still return from current callback iteration? `cb(); return;` EDIT: i see in OP's code it won't make much difference but using `return;` would be more optimized and explicit

Comment: he already mentioned that `return;` is not working for him, thats why I suggest to just call his `cb` function